# Incremental data processing for file in talend

Tags: etl, talend

How can you manage your incremental data processing when you don't have database or anything to log the previous execution timestamp?
Can we use tAddCRCRow component? But How come will it know that if this data has been processed already or not specially when both sorce and destinations are nothing but collections of file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use your target file as a lookup and identify the existing value. This will help you to resolve your issue.

In case of files, you have to use multiple file as a lookup. Or create a separate table which holds the unique value of all the files and use it as a lookup

Comment: Thank you so much @Jim Macaulay for your response. my target is collection of files and not a single file.

Comment: Then you have to use multiple file as a lookup. Or create a separate table which holds the unique value of all the files and use it as a lookup

Comment: Thank you @Jim Macaulay, I got an idea from your response. I can use tUnite to create single file from all file of target and can use output of tUnite as lookup, right?

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. But please consider the performance while applying the logic. If you feel you are happy with the answer please upvote it